# how to diff automatically between file.txt.orig and file.txt

Tags: diff, patch

Currently, I am editing files on vim by setting `patchmode=.orig` and then, having two files:

1. `file.txt.orig` <- backup without changes
2. `file.txt` <- update file

However, I would like to generate a diff without having to rename the `.orig` file, so `patch` understands it is just `file.txt` which has been updated.

Ideally I would really enjoy a workflow I could run

`diff -u file.txt` which would automatically compare `file.txt.orig` and `file.txt` and output a `.diff` containing

```diff
--- file.txt    2021-05-03 17:47:12.685416342 +0200
+++ file.txt    2021-05-03 17:47:30.538750593 +0200
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 foo bar
+bar baz
```

instead of `diff -u file.txt.orig file.txt`

```diff
--- file.txt.orig   2021-05-03 17:47:12.685416342 +0200
+++ file.txt    2021-05-03 17:47:30.538750593 +0200
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 foo bar
+bar baz
```

The above does require me to manually edit the `.diff` file every time.
If using `.orig` files automatically, would be possible at all, I would love to integrate vim patchmode with `diff` and have a valid patch without extra effort.

Perhaps there's an even better approach to this? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Both `diff` or `git diff` would work for my case.

Comment: If you explicitly specify the file you want to patch (like `patch file.txt <file.diff`), `patch` doesn't care about what file name is written inside `file.diff`.

Comment: Thank you, raj. That was very insightful as I had no idea that the file name was irrelevant for both `patch` and `git apply`. It makes more sense to me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workflow works for me. Perhaps you're testing by trying to apply the patch the file you've previously updated?

Preparation

```
echo this is original >file.txt.orig
echo this is new >file.txt
diff -u file.txt.orig file.txt >file.diff

cat file.diff
--- file.txt.orig       2021-05-03 19:17:13.038918015 +0100
+++ file.txt    2021-05-03 19:17:21.548900027 +0100
@@ -1 +1 @@
-this is original
+this is new
```

Create copy of original file to patch

```
mkdir x
cp -p file.txt.orig x/file.txt
cd x

cat file.txt
this is original

patch <../file.diff
patching file file.txt

cat file.txt
this is new
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example, roaima. You were right I about me patching a previously updated patch causing an unexpected behaviour. After checking your example I now realized that the name of the original file doesn't really matter as raj pointed out on his comment.

Comment: Notice in my example that I specifically do not mention the file to be patched - I leave that for `patch` to infer from the patch file